# svn pre-commit hook check java source

Tags: java, svn, triggers, pre-commit-hook

I want to check whether some particular Java classes want to be commited. If so, I want to check if `serialVersionUID` is changed inside source of that particular class (new and old value).

How to do it? Any examples PLS.

Regards

Comment: Are you asking how to add an SVN hook, how to check for serialVersionUID, or both?

Comment: The correct way would involve compiling that source and then reading the `serialVersionUID` field from the bytecode.  This is almost certainly implausible, so you might be able to use a regex if you make assumptions about the format of the code.  Just bear in mind that without a Java lexer/parser, it will always be possible for the source to contain a `serialVersionUID` declaration that you don't pick up.

Comment: Why not just have the SVN pre-commit hook auto increment the serialVersionUID?  That way, the hook knows the format of the Java statement, and your developers have one less thing to worry about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to find plenty of examples on the web about setting up SVN hooks -- here is the [relevant chapter from the SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch05s02.html).  Scroll down to *Hook Scripts*.

As to detecting `serialVersionUID` I share similar views to Andrzej Doyle: if you're parsing the source code, there will likely be cases where you'll incorrectly detect it.  However, your source code in question may be simple enough that it works 99% of the time -- and the ramifications of getting it wrong may not be too disastrous.  Only you know the answer to that.

So, a *really simple* way to check for it (assuming a Linux/UNIX/Mac OS environment) is to use a shell script that uses `grep` to look for 'serialVersionUID'.  However, I can immediately think of a way this could detect a false positive: if an inner class declares it, a simple grep would detect it for the containing class (since we're not parsing the file, we have no knowledge of the actual class structure inside).

Comment: For start I'll try simple solution assuming that there is no inner class defined. I'll post solution as soon as I make one. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use continuous integration server like [jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/)
and create jobs that check stuff
and send out emails when stuff happens

:)